# bypass cookiewall selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to scrape job listings from a Dutch job listings website. However, when I try to open the page with selenium I run into a cookiewall (new GDPR rules). How do I bypass the cookiewall?

```
import selenium 

#launch url
url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl/vacature/zoeken?query=&location=&distance=city&limit=100&sort=relevance&filters%5BcareerLevel%5D%5B%5D=Starter&filters%5BeducationLevel%5D%5B%5D=MBO"

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
```

**Edit I tried something**

```
import selenium 
import pickle

url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl/vacature/zoeken?query=&location=&distance=city&limit=100&sort=relevance&filters%5BcareerLevel%5D%5B%5D=Starter&filters%5BeducationLevel%5D%5B%5D=MBO"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
driver.get(start_url)

pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("NVBCookies.pkl","wb"))
```

after that loading the cookies did not work

```
for cookie in pickle.load(open("NVBCookies.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Cookies may only be set for the current domain (cookiewall.vnumediaonline.nl)
```

It looks like I don't get the cookies from the cookiewall, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_save"]').click()
```

ok I made selenium click the accept button. Also fine by me. Not sure if I'll run into cookiewalls later

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bypassing why don't you write code to check if it's present then accept it otherwise continue with next operation.  Please find below code for more details

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\New folder (2)\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl/vacature/zoeken?query=&location=&distance=city&limit=100&sort=relevance&filters%5BcareerLevel%5D%5B%5D=Starter&filters%5BeducationLevel%5D%5B%5D=MBO")

        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='article__button']//button[@id='form_save']")
        elem.click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: FYI: I'm a novice programmer. 
To me, it sounds as if that check always comes back true unless I accept manually...right? Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean with just accepting it. I don't want to accept cookies by hand every time I run my code

Comment: @Lunalight , I think answerer meant *accept by clicking Accept button programmatically*

Comment: @dbachhav , this doesn't really answers the question. If you want to ask OP for some more details - leave a comment under the question

Comment: @Andersson I tried to do it programmatically but don't think I got the right element

Comment: @Lunalight , share code for the same along with Exception log (update your question)

Comment: @Andersson I overwrote that bit of code. My version control is nonexistent, sorry.

Comment: @dbachhav I get: SystemExit: True

Comment: @Lunalight : Show me your stack trace

Comment: `======================================================================
ERROR: C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-6c112eff-b5a4-4071-aa74-77bdf3024551 (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-6c112eff-b5a4-4071-aa74-77bdf3024551'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)`